# Why kpr() shows different content than var_dump()?

Tags: debugging

In one vital part of code I started to get "Trying to get a property on a non-object" type of errors. So I wanted to investigate it.

```
var_dump($download);
die();
```

Gives:

```
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    [5]=>
    object(stdClass)#156 (11) {
      ["idDownload"]=>
      string(1) "5"
      ...
    }
    [6]=>
    object(stdClass)#155 (11) {
      ["idDownload"]=>
      string(1) "6"
      ...
    }
    [7]=>
    object(stdClass)#151 (11) {
      ["idDownload"]=>
      string(1) "7"
      ...
    }
    [8]=>
    object(stdClass)#185 (11) {
      ["idDownload"]=>
      ...
    }
    [10]=>
    object(stdClass)#177 (11) {
      ["idDownload"]=>
      string(2) "10"
      ...
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(5) {
    [5]=>
    object(stdClass)#186 (11) {
      ["idDownload"]=>
      string(1) "5"
      ...
    }
    [6]=>
    object(stdClass)#155 (11) {
      ["idDownload"]=>
      string(1) "6"
      ...
    }
    [7]=>
    object(stdClass)#151 (11) {
      ["idDownload"]=>
      string(1) "7"
      ...
    }
    [10]=>
    object(stdClass)#177 (11) {
      ["idDownload"]=>
      string(2) "10"
      ...
    }
  }
  [3]=>
  array(5) {
    [5]=>
    object(stdClass)#184 (11) {
      ["idDownload"]=>
      string(1) "5"
      ...
    }
    [6]=>
    object(stdClass)#155 (11) {
      ["idDownload"]=>
      string(1) "6"
      ...
    }
    [7]=>
    object(stdClass)#151 (11) {
      ["idDownload"]=>
      string(1) "7"
      ...
    }
    [8]=>
    object(stdClass)#185 (11) {
      ["idDownload"]=>
      string(1) "8"
      ...
    }
    [10]=>
    object(stdClass)#177 (11) {
      ["idDownload"]=>
      string(2) "10"
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

But if I'll switch to kpr() like this:

```
kpr($download);
//die();
```

I get this:

[image: Screenshot]

Why can it happen? And can how I get `kpr()` to work? using `var_dump()` in form debugging is not really an option.

Comment: Note: I don't think it's really a bug in devel module, because I know for a fact that *something* is wrong with my data. It's just that on `var_dump()` objects  `5` and `6` looks exactly alike, and on `kpr()` they don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$download[1][6]` and `$download[2][6]` are the exact same object (`object(stdClass)#155`), not just two objects with equal values. To avoid potential infinite recursion, Krumo (the k in `kpr()`) only display a single object once. The screenshot shows this, `$download[2][6]` is displayed as "∞ (Recursion)" because the object is already displayed (but collapsed in the screenshot) above as `$download[1][6]`.

`var_dump()` does not have this *limitation* as it does not try to prevent infinite recursion.